# Python Selenium webdriver element finding by link text

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, findelement

I´m trying to enter a webside world with selenium with this code:

```
World_select = driver.find_element_by_link_text('USA 15')
World_select.click()
```

Even with this code I can´t enter it.

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('USA 15').click()
```

The terminal sends me a traceback witch I dont really understand how to fix it.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: USA 15
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What webpage you are traying it on?

Comment: https://lordsandknights.com/   You enter this webside and then you can choose a world. I want to create a programm where you can choose in witch world you want to go. But for that I need to get all of the links. Here is a screenshot : https://prnt.sc/wf8igw

Comment: Well, the error you are getting "NoSuchElementException" means exactly what it says. You probably want to wait for the element to appear, the page is loading for like 30s for me...

Comment: Other than that, it looks ok, I tried `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("at vrá").click()` on https://www.eztraty.cz/founds. It seems it is taking spaces and correctly finds the button and clicks it...

Comment: You need to post more of your code so we can see what you doing and what you are *not* doing. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).